# What is wrong with this code as the answer to the following online judge problem?

Tags: c++, geometry

The problem states that given the radius of three circles, and assuming that three circles touch themselves in a way shown:

[image: in this figure]

we need to find out the area of the blue portion between them. I have written the following code and run a few test cases. All of them worked fine. The online judge says the answer is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double r1, r2, r3, tarea, r1area, r2area, r3area;
    long double res;
    int i, test;
    cin >> test;
    for(i = 1;i <= test;i++)
    {
        cin >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;
        tarea = sqrt(((r1 + r2 + r3)*r1*r2*r3));
        r1area = 0.5*(r1*r1)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r1+r3))));
        r2area = 0.5*(r2*r2)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r2+r3)*(r1+r3))));
        r3area = 0.5*(r3*r3)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r2+r3))));
        res = tarea - (r1area + r2area + r3area);
        cout << "Case " << i << ": " << fixed << setprecision(8) << res << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what formula you're using, but your `rNarea` formulas don't appear to be consistent. What is the relation between the numerator and the denominator supposed to be?

Comment: I did some math and used this formula as shortcut.I think the problem is elsewhere @cigien

Comment: are you sure the formulas are correct? I'd expect some symmetry with respect to `r1`,`r1` and `r2` but I dont see it in your formulas

Comment: Undo your "shortcut" and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: Perhaps show the math you used to get the shortcut for the formulas. As @idclev463035818 says, the formulas don't appear to be symmetrical, and appear to be dependent on the order of the inputs, which would be odd.

Comment: *The online judge says the answer is wrong* -- What did the "online judge" say was the correct answer?  Note that you are using floating point math, so what if your answer is "wrong" only because of round-off error?  Also, I noticed that many, if not most of these questions from online judge sites stay away from anything to do with floating point, due to the inaccuracies that can occur.

Comment: Try `r2area = 0.5*(r2*r2)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r2+r3)*(r1+r3))));` -> `r2area = 0.5*(r2*r2)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r2+r3)*(r1+r2))));` and `r3area = 0.5*(r3*r3)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r2+r3))));` -> `r3area = 0.5*(r3*r3)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r3)*(r2+r3))));`

Comment: I'm with @cigien here. If you flip r3 an r1, this formula give you different result, which doesn't make sense. Fix the maths ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik, I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the formulas:

```
r1area = 0.5*(r1*r1)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r1+r3))));
r2area = 0.5*(r2*r2)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r2+r3)*(r1+r3))));
r3area = 0.5*(r3*r3)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r2+r3))));
res = tarea - (r1area + r2area + r3area);
```

Without entering into the details of the maths I know that they cannot be correct. Why? Symmetry! The final result does not change if you permute the labeling of the circles. This is fine for the last line, because with

```
auto a = r1area;
auto b = r2area;
auto c = r3area;
```

all those expressions yield the same result:

```
res = tarea - (a + b + c);
res = tarea - (a + c + b);
res = tarea - (b + a + c);
res = tarea - (b + c + a);
....
```

Similarly you should get the same result for permutations of `r1`,`r2` and `r3` and this is not the case.

This

```
r1area = 0.5*(r1*r1)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r1+r2)*(r1+r3))));
```

can be rewritten as

```
r1area = calc_area( r1*r1, r1+r2, r1+r3);
```

or

```
Aarea = calc_area( A*A, A+B, A+C);
```

Because of the symmetry of the problem, it should be possible to get the forumla for `Barea` by permuting `A`,`B` and `C`, but if we swap `A` and `B` (those are just labels!) then we get

```
Barea = calc_area( B*B, B+A, B+C);
```

while you have:

```
r2area = 0.5*(r2*r2)*(asin((2*tarea)/((r2+r3)*(r1+r3))));
// ->
r2area = calc_area( r2*r2, r2+r3, r1+r3);
// ->
Barea = calc_area( B*B, B+C, A+C);
```

Note that the last parameter is `B+C` vs `A+C`, ie `XArea` has `X+Y,X+Z` in one case but `X+Y,Y+Z` in the other. Hence no permutation of the labels can make those formulas the same. However, the area between the circles will not change if you put different labels on the circles, ergo your formulas cannot be correct.

Comment: Thanks @idclev463035818, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of simmetry in the formula is a strong evidence that something is wrong in the posted code, as shown in [idclev 463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/idclev-463035818)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196667/4944425).

There's another mathematical issue, though, that may come up in the tests.

The code tries to implement the law of sines, in order to calculate the angles of the triangle formed by the centers of the circles. The problem is that when one of the radii is small enough, the corresponding angle in the triangle become **obtuse** and the chosen formula doesn't hold anymore.

Consider the documentation of [`std::asin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/asin), the returned value is in the range **[-π/2, π/2]**, it can't represent an obtuse angle.

We could rewrite the formulas using the law of cosines (which doesn't have this issue) or we could just evaluate the greatest angle remembering that the three interior angles of a triangle add up to π.

```
#include <cmath>

#if __has_include(<numbers>)
#   include <numbers>
#else
namespace std::numbers {
    inline constexpr double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
}
#endif


double area_circumscribed_by_circles(double r1, double r2, double r3)
{
    // I want the third to have the smaller radius.
    if (r1 < r2) {
        if ( r1 < r3 )
            std::swap(r1, r3);
    } else {
        if ( r2 < r3 )
            std::swap(r2, r3);
    }

    if (r3 == 0.0)
        return 0.0;

    // Apply Heron's formula to find the area of the triangle
    // formed by the centers of the circles.
    double area = std::sqrt((r1 + r2 + r3) * r1 * r2 * r3);

    // Find the first two angles using the law of sines.
    double angle_1 = std::asin(2.0 * area / ((r1 + r2) * (r1 + r3)));
    double angle_2 = std::asin(2.0 * area / ((r2 + r1) * (r2 + r3)));

    // The third angle may be obtuse, we can't use the previous formula.
    double angle_3 = std::numbers::pi - (angle_1 + angle_2);

    // Now we can subtract the area of the sectors.
    return area - 0.5 * (r1 * r1 * angle_1 + r2 * r2 * angle_2 + r3 * r3 * angle_3);
}
```